# Can an object throw itself?

Tags: c++, exception

Answering a recent question on exceptions, reminded me of an old query.

The following compiles in c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct weird {
    void danger()
    {
        throw *this;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    weird object;
    object.danger();
    return 0;
}
```

Yet it always results in runtime error.

- Isn't the object thrown, preserved during stack unwinding?
- The runtime error smells like a call to `terminate`, how is this caused?
- If `weird object` was declared in an enclosing scope (the global here) could this work in an inner scope? (where unwinding that stack wouldn't affect superior ones?)

Comment: You're not catching the exception - so that'll normally terminate an application.

Comment: Though the main issue is not attempting to `catch` at all, note that `throw` always throws "by value", so the exception object is a copy of the object in `main`.  That copy will survive until the exception is handled, even if the original has been destroyed.

Comment: Yep, too drawn into the whole `throw this` that I missed the obvious

Comment: When you say `throw 1;`, what happens to the `1` when you go out of scope?

Comment: @KerrekSB Nothing I suppose, numerals are not objects, have no address nor can they get out of scope.

Comment: Numerals aren't objects (they're character literals), but integers are, and integers have addresses and go out of scope...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The result is a call to `std::terminate()` because the exception is never caught. Change it to the following and it works fine:

```
int main() {
    weird object;
    try {
      object.danger();
    }
    catch (weird &w) {
      std::cout << "caught weird\n";   
    }
}
```

> - Isn't the object thrown, preserved during stack unwinding?

When an exception is thrown, the exception throwing mechanism makes a copy of the thrown value into some private memory somewhere, so the lifetime of the 'thrown' object does not matter.

(Of course if you throw a pointer then the pointer value is preserved, not the pointed-to object. In that case you must ensure that catch handlers do not do illegal things with the pointer value, either by ensuring the object still exists, or that the catch handler does not deference the pointer.)

> - The runtime error smells like a call to `terminate`, how is this caused?

When an exception is thrown and there is no corresponding catch handler C++ states that `std::terminate()` must be called. The exception throwing mechanism responsible for finding an appropriate catch handler implements this by calling `std::terminate()` when it fails to find an appropriate catch handler.

> - If `weird object` was declared in an enclosing scope (the global here) could this work in an inner scope?

Whether it's global or not doesn't matter; the behavior of throwing the exception is (mostly) well defined either way.

(One thing that's implementation specified is if the stack gets unwound before `std::terminate()` is called when no catch handler is found. I believe that on most implementations the stack is not unwound in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

When it goes to exceptions in C++, remember this: ***Throw by value, catch by reference***.

"by value" = copying, copying = you don't need to care about what happens to original object anymore.

---

Side note: If you are going to `throw` own types, you better derive them from `std::exception`.